# Make embed's color the display color of the author of the command discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make it so when I do a command in discord.js the bot will create an embed with the author's display color.

```
let colour = message.member.displayHexColor;
let color = colour.slice(1).trim().split(/ +/g);
message.channel.send({embed: {
    color: `${color}`,
    description: "A very simple Embed!"
}});
```

But it seems embed.color must be in decimal form. "displayHexColor" gets the user's color in hexadecimal.  How can I convert it or get the user's display color in decimal

Comment: Check out [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/6ov372/how_does_the_color_code_for_bot_embeds_work/) where people give an answer. Basically all you'd need to do is format the color like `0x<hexvalue without the #>`

Answer (score 0):

e.e documentation

Instead of using .displayHexColor, you can use .displayColor to get the color in base 10 (decimal)